# How to filtering listview from sqlite field?

Tags: android, arrays, sqlite, listview, filtering

I want to make a tools that filtering my listview depend my database. I can filtering data from string [] array, but when I try this on my record from database. I got this error `adapter cannot be resolved to a variable`

in this line

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<product>(ViewData.this, R.layout.item_list, R.id.edtnama, brand);
```

and this line

```
ListView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

This is a full code

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.viewdata);

    dataSource = new DBDataSource(this);
    dataSource.open();
    brand = dataSource.getAllproduct();

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<product>(ViewData.this, R.layout.item_list, R.id.edtnama, brand);
    ListView.setAdapter(adapter);
    edtsearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtsearch);

    edtsearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count){
            ViewData.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(s);
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after){}

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s){}  
    });
```

Comment: Are you using a custom adapter?

Comment: Have you make adapter variable global??

Comment: no i am not using custom adapter

Comment: ArrayAdapter adapter; like this

Comment: i try to insert private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter; and i got another error "cannot convert from ArrayList<product> to ArrayList<String>"

Comment: Ok...and make it before call onCreate method

Comment: when i use "Private ArrayAdapter<product> adapter; this error that i get "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method setAdapter(ListAdapter) from the type ListView"

Comment: Make only ArrayAdapter<product> adapter; and if you are using ListActivity then lnly set setListAdapter(adapter);

Comment: u got it.. it works...thanks piyush...